# springboot 3.0 restTemplate with SSLHostNameVerifier

Tags: spring-boot

We are upgrading to springboot 3.0 and we have the following resttemplate code.The following code creating issue at CloseableHttpClient   and NoopHostnameVerifier.We are upgrading this app to springboot 3.0.

`

```
@Bean public RestTemplate restTemplate() { 
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
CloseableHttpClient  httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()) .build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory( httpClient);
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory); 
return  restTemplate;
}
```

`
We are noware found NoopHostnameVerifier,CloseableHttpClient.Any help is appreciated.

Upgrade to spring boot 3

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can set this with *SSLConnectionSocketFactory* and then add this to your connectionManager.

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory =  new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
HttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
            .build();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
        .build();
```

You can also use *new NoopHostnameVerifier()* instead.